# how to check if text is clipping after translation in windows based application design in delphi

Tags: delphi, language-translation

I have built a windows based application in Delphi programming language. My application consist of lots of screens with labels, button, memo etc., Currently my application is in English language and i want to translate it in other languages and i use Multilizer tool to do that, but after translation most of my text is clipped, but some components are of variable length so they are fine

So is there any way can test which text is clipping and because my application is very big and it is not possible to test it manually

Comment: but i am not inserting translated text myself multilizer tool do this for me which accept exe and create a new exe in translated language

Comment: How else are you going to measure the width of text. Maybe you need to develop some tooling. Do you know how to program or are you just transforming someone else's app. If it's your code you can tool up. In any case, whatever the scenario is, I suggest that you do what you claim is impossible. Test your app. If you won't test it it won't look right.

Comment: Such translation tool would have to know where the text is being rendered for every single component at least at default window size (which is *unknown* yet when you set your window to be maximized). Also do note, that some of the components may render differently on certain conditions, some might be resized at runtime by runtime conditions. What you are asking is almost impossible. Even a runtime routine for handling all the situations would be difficult to write. @David, `TextWidth` is useless when controls calculate (and render) their word wrapped text e.g. by `DrawTextEx` function.

Comment: @tlama when the program calcs size at runtime it can just get it right no?

Comment: so first i iterate all component and find there length and compare it with translated text

Comment: @DavidHeffernan this is my application and can you explain me what you you mean by tool up

Comment: Write some tooling to help you. You can build it into the app.

Comment: @David, controls rendering word wrapped text (e.g. `TLabel` with `WordWrap == True`) can clip their text content as well (as long as they are not set to autosize). And for those is `TextWidth` not enough. It's a bunch of work I've already gone through and we've finally decided to provide a runtime designer where the translators could write their translations in the running app (and optionally resize the controls a bit). Except that our intercepted controls automatically used hints when their texts were *clipped* (by ellipsis).

Comment: The version specific tags are meant to convey meaning. Please don't add them at random.